# Downgrade to python 3.5 to use tensorflow

Tags: windows, python-3.x, tensorflow, installation, anaconda

I am following a tutorial about deep learning with keras. I have managed to install keras through anaconda. It also requires tensorflow which I have failed to install properly. From the related posts, python 3.5 and 64 bit are required to run tf. The version under anaconda is 3.6 and when I tried to downgrade it with `conda install python=3.5`, it started the procedure but after a while it threw the following:

```
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

    anaconda:            custom-py36_0      --> custom-py35_0
    python:              3.6.1-2            --> 3.5.3-3
```

And now when I activate tensorflow and run "python" on pycharm terminal, it gets:

```
Python 3.5.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, May 15 2017, 10:43:23) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

In addition, I have already installed tensorflow and I have a tensorflow folder under Anaconda/envs folder. And finally under that folder, I have all the files and documents related to tensorflow. However, when I try to import it as:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

It throws `No module named 'tensorflow'`.

What am I missing?

Comment: There's a reason everyone's using 2.7

Comment: @MaxB there is no released windows version for python2.7, the only version [currently available for windows](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow) is for python3.5. There are reasons why many projects are dropping support for python2.7.

Comment: @mlee_jordan if you solved your problem, then you should post your resolution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I had installed tf following the steps given here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

However, it was still version 3.6 and did not work out. After downgrading to 3.5, I had to remove all previously set environments and then need to re-install again. When doing that it worked. Here are the steps I followed:

```
conda remove --name tensorflow --all
conda create -n tensorflow 
activate tensorflow
https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```